# Update table with Javascript after form submit - not working in IE & Edge

Tags: javascript, mysql, wordpress, submit

I use Contact Form 7 in Wordpress to save data into a MySQL Database with Submit-Form. Now I need to reload a table which contains these data after I submit the form. I am using following script:

```
/* FORM RELOAD AFTER SUBMIT */
jQuery("form").submit(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery("#table-div").load(document.URL +  ' #table-div > table');
    }, 500);
});
```

I tried to use the timeout because to give some time to save the data and get it back. It actually works fine in almost all browsers (FF, Chrome, IE...) but its not working in IE & Edge and I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });. Now its working, script:

```
/* FORM RELOAD AFTER SUBMIT  */
jQuery("form").submit(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery("#table-div").load(document.URL + '?1234' + ' #table-div > table');
    }, 500);
});
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```